# Convert byte array to string in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, string

I have byte data of .doc, .txt, .docx and I want to convert it to string, I did following things but not getting exact result:

```
Public ByteData As Byte() = // my data
Dim str As String = String.Empty

str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(objCandidateInfo.ByteData, 0, objCandidateInfo.ByteData.Length)
str = Convert.ToBase64String(objCandidateInfo.ByteData)
```

**Edited**

So now I am converting the same using Word Application, this code is working 
this is my code

```
 Private Shared ObjwordApp As Word.Application
    Private Shared nullobj As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Private Shared doc As Word.Document
    Shared Sub New()
        ObjwordApp = New Word.Application()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub InitializeClass()
        ObjwordApp.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub OpenWordFile(ByVal StrFilePath As Object)
        Try
            ObjwordApp.Visible = False
        Catch ex As Exception
            ObjwordApp = New Word.Application()
        End Try
        Try
            doc = ObjwordApp.Documents.Open(StrFilePath, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj)
        Catch ex As Exception
            CloseWordFile()
            ObjwordApp.Visible = False
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub CopyWordContent()
        Try
            doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory()
            doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Clipboard.Clear()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub CloseWordFile()
        Try
            doc.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ReadWordFile(ByVal StrFilePath As String, ByVal StrDataFormat As String) As String
        Dim StrFileContent = String.Empty
        If (File.Exists(StrFilePath)) Then
            Try
                OpenWordFile(StrFilePath)
                CopyWordContent()
            Catch ex As Exception

            Finally
                CloseWordFile()
            End Try

            Try
                Dim dataObj As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
                If (dataObj.GetDataPresent(StrDataFormat)) Then
                    StrFileContent = dataObj.GetData(StrDataFormat)
                Else
                    StrFileContent = ""
                End If
                Clipboard.Clear()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End If
        Return StrFileContent
    End Function
```

And when I saving the byte array to DB, I call below function and convert it to rtf, it is  not converting, when I attach debugger to it `dataObj` is `Nothing`

**code 1**

```
Dim str As String = String.Empty
                Try
                    'str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(objCandidateInfo.ByteData, 0, objCandidateInfo.ByteData.Length)
                    'str = Convert.ToBase64String(objCandidateInfo.ByteData)
                    'str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(objCandidateInfo.ByteData, 0, objCandidateInfo.ByteData.Length)
                    str = ClsDocumentManager.ReadContent(objCandidateInfo.ByteData, DataFormats.Rtf)
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
```

I save data db in both byte and text format, so when I call it from db (byte value that I save and convert it to rtf), its working the code is

**Code 2**

```
rtbAttachment.Rtf = ClsDocumentManager.ReadContent(byteAttachment, DataFormats.Rtf)
```

These are the methods in `ClsDocumentManager` class

```
Public Shared Function GetRandomNo() As Integer
        Dim RandomNo As New Random()
        Return RandomNo.Next(Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now().Minute.ToString() & DateTime.Now().Second.ToString() & DateTime.Now().Hour.ToString()))
    End Function

    Public Shared Function ReadContent(ByVal byteArray As Byte(), ByVal StrReadFormat As String) As String
        Dim StrFileContent As String = String.Empty
        Try
            If (Not IsNothing(byteArray)) Then
                Dim StrFileName As String = GetRandomNo().ToString() & ".doc"
                StrFileName = ClsSingleton.aTempFolderName & StrFileName
                If (CreateWordFile(byteArray, StrFileName)) Then
                    StrFileContent = ClsWordManager.ReadWordFile(StrFileName, StrReadFormat)
                    If (File.Exists(StrFileName)) Then
                        File.Delete(StrFileName)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Return StrFileContent
    End Function

Public Shared Function CreateWordFile(ByVal byteArray As Byte(), ByVal StrFileName As String) As Boolean
        Dim boolResult As Boolean = False
        Try
            If (Not IsNothing(byteArray)) Then
                If (Not File.Exists(StrFileName)) Then
                    Dim objFileStream As New FileStream(StrFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                    objFileStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
                    objFileStream.Close()
                    boolResult = True
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            boolResult = False
        End Try
        Return boolResult
    End Function
```

**Error Code** while debugging

```
Dim dataObj As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
                If (dataObj.GetDataPresent(StrDataFormat)) Then
                    StrFileContent = dataObj.GetData(StrDataFormat)
                Else
                    StrFileContent = ""
                End If

`dataObj` is `Nothing` only when calling from **Code 1**
```

**Updated**

```
**`ClsDocumentManager`**



Imports System.IO

Public Class ClsDocumentManager
    Public Shared Function GetRandomNo() As Integer
        Dim RandomNo As New Random()
        Return RandomNo.Next(Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now().Minute.ToString() & DateTime.Now().Second.ToString() & DateTime.Now().Hour.ToString()))
    End Function

    Public Shared Function ReadContent(ByVal byteArray As Byte(), ByVal StrReadFormat As String) As String
        Dim StrFileContent As String = String.Empty
        Try
            If (Not IsNothing(byteArray)) Then
                Dim StrFileName As String = GetRandomNo().ToString() & ".doc"
                StrFileName = ClsSingleton.aTempFolderName & StrFileName
                If (CreateWordFile(byteArray, StrFileName)) Then
                    StrFileContent = ClsWordManager.ReadWordFile(StrFileName, StrReadFormat)
                    If (File.Exists(StrFileName)) Then
                        File.Delete(StrFileName)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Return StrFileContent
    End Function


    Public Shared Function CreateWordFile(ByVal byteArray As Byte(), ByVal StrFileName As String) As Boolean
        Dim boolResult As Boolean = False
        Try
            If (Not IsNothing(byteArray)) Then
                If (Not File.Exists(StrFileName)) Then
                    Dim objFileStream As New FileStream(StrFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                    objFileStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
                    objFileStream.Close()
                    boolResult = True
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            boolResult = False
        End Try
        Return boolResult
    End Function
End Class
```

Here is my `ClsWordManager` Class

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class ClsWordManager
    Private Shared ObjwordApp As Word.Application
    Private Shared nullobj As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Private Shared doc As Word.Document
    Shared Sub New()
        ObjwordApp = New Word.Application()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub InitializeClass()
        ObjwordApp.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub OpenWordFile(ByVal StrFilePath As Object)
        Try
            ObjwordApp.Visible = False
        Catch ex As Exception
            ObjwordApp = New Word.Application()
        End Try
        Try
            doc = ObjwordApp.Documents.Open(StrFilePath, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj)
        Catch ex As Exception
            CloseWordFile()
            ObjwordApp.Visible = False
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub CopyWordContent()
        Try
            doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory()
            doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Clipboard.Clear()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub CloseWordFile()
        Try
            doc.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ReadWordFile(ByVal StrFilePath As String, ByVal StrDataFormat As String) As String
        Dim StrFileContent = String.Empty
        If (File.Exists(StrFilePath)) Then
            Try
                OpenWordFile(StrFilePath)
                CopyWordContent()
            Catch ex As Exception

            Finally
                CloseWordFile()
            End Try

            Try
                Dim dataObj As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
                If (dataObj.GetDataPresent(StrDataFormat)) Then
                    StrFileContent = dataObj.GetData(StrDataFormat)
                Else
                    StrFileContent = ""
                End If
                Clipboard.Clear()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End If
        Return StrFileContent
    End Function



End Class
```

So now the problem is When I convert it in following code : look at `ByteAttachmets` in arguement, it convert byte to string

```
Public Function UpdateCandidateAttachment(ByVal CandidateID As Integer, ByVal ByteAttachmets As Byte(), ByVal StrExtension As String) As Integer
        Dim Result As Integer = -1
        Try
            Dim objDataLayer As New ClsDataLayer()
            Dim str As String = Nothing
            Try
                'str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(objCandidateInfo.ByteData, 0, objCandidateInfo.ByteData.Length)
                'str = Convert.ToBase64String(objCandidateInfo.ByteData)
                'str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(objCandidateInfo.ByteData, 0, objCandidateInfo.ByteData.Length)
                str = ClsDocumentManager.ReadContent(ByteAttachmets, DataFormats.Rtf)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            objDataLayer.AddParameter("@CANDIDATE_ID", CandidateID)
            objDataLayer.AddParameter("@ATTACHMENT_DATA", ByteAttachmets)
            objDataLayer.AddParameter("@CREATED_BY", ClsCommons.IntUserId)
            objDataLayer.AddParameter("@EXTENSION", StrExtension)
            Result = objDataLayer.ExecuteNonQuery("TR_PROC_UpdateCandidateAttachment")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return Result
    End Function
```

And when I call it from following code by property : look at `objCandidateInfo.ByteData`, it is not working.

```
Public Function AddUpdateCandidate(ByVal objCandidateInfo As ClsCandidateInfo) As Integer
        Dim Result As Integer = -1
        Try
            If (ClsCommons.IsValidEmail(objCandidateInfo.StrEmail)) Then
                Dim str As String = Nothing
                Try
                    'str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(objCandidateInfo.ByteData, 0, objCandidateInfo.ByteData.Length)
                    'str = Convert.ToBase64String(objCandidateInfo.ByteData)
                    'str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(objCandidateInfo.ByteData, 0, objCandidateInfo.ByteData.Length)
                    Dim byteAttachment As Byte() = objCandidateInfo.ByteData
                    str = ClsDocumentManager.ReadContent(byteAttachment, DataFormats.Rtf)
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
                Dim objDataLayer As New ClsDataLayer()
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@REQUIREMENT_ID", objCandidateInfo.RequirementId)
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Candidate_Name", objCandidateInfo.StrCandidateName)
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Current_Organization", objCandidateInfo.StrCurrentCompany)
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Current_Designation", objCandidateInfo.StrCurrentDesignation)
                If (objCandidateInfo.StrExp.Trim() = "") Then
                    objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Overall_Exp", DBNull.Value)
                Else
                    Dim DecExp As Decimal = -1
                    If (Decimal.TryParse(objCandidateInfo.StrExp, DecExp)) Then
                        objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Overall_Exp", DecExp)
                    Else
                        objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Overall_Exp", DBNull.Value)
                    End If
                End If
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Qualification", objCandidateInfo.StrQualification)
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Location", objCandidateInfo.StrCurrentLocation)
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Current_CTC", objCandidateInfo.StrCurrentCTC)
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Expected_CTC", objCandidateInfo.StrExpectedCTC)
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Phone_No", objCandidateInfo.StrPhoneNo)
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Mobile", objCandidateInfo.StrMobile)
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Notice_Period", objCandidateInfo.StrNoticePeriod)
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Remarks", objCandidateInfo.StrRemarks)
                If (objCandidateInfo.StrYearofExp.Trim() = "") Then
                    objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Years_of_Experience", DBNull.Value)
                Else
                    Dim DecExp As Decimal = -1
                    If (Decimal.TryParse(objCandidateInfo.StrYearofExp, DecExp)) Then
                        objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Years_of_Experience", DecExp)
                    Else
                        objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Years_of_Experience", DBNull.Value)
                    End If
                End If
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Address", objCandidateInfo.StrAddress)

                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Email", objCandidateInfo.StrEmail)
                If (objCandidateInfo.intIndustry > 0) Then
                    objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Industry", objCandidateInfo.intIndustry)
                Else
                    objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Industry", DBNull.Value)
                End If
                If (objCandidateInfo.intFunctionalArea > 0) Then
                    objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Functional_Area", objCandidateInfo.intFunctionalArea)
                Else
                    objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Functional_Area", DBNull.Value)
                End If
                If (objCandidateInfo.StrDob.Trim() = "") Then
                    objDataLayer.AddParameter("@DOB", DBNull.Value)
                Else
                    Try
                        objDataLayer.AddParameter("@DOB", Convert.ToDateTime(objCandidateInfo.StrDob))
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        objDataLayer.AddParameter("@DOB", DBNull.Value)
                    End Try
                End If
                If (objCandidateInfo.intSourceBy > 0) Then
                    objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Source", objCandidateInfo.intSourceBy)
                Else
                    objDataLayer.AddParameter("@Source", DBNull.Value)
                End If
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@SKILL_SET", objCandidateInfo.strSkillSet)
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@ATTACHMENT_DATA", objCandidateInfo.ByteData)
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@EXTENSION", objCandidateInfo.StrExtension)
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@CREATED_BY", ClsCommons.IntUserId)

                Result = objDataLayer.ExecuteNonQuery("TR_PROC_AddUpdateFullCandidateData")
            Else
                MsgBox("Data is not extracted, Some Error Occured, please update your software.")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return Result
    End Function
```

I hope I clear my query

Comment: A string of what? You want a string of the text inside the document?

Comment: I want to convert .doc byte array to string mean text of the .doc file

Comment: .doc file format is a proprietary binary format, you can't easily get its contents out into a string.

Comment: This is a very poor question because of all the cruft.  In the future boil the problem down to the smallest code sample that illustrates the issue - and leave all the stuff that detracts from the issue out of the post.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited after several changes to question.)

If you only want to get the text content of the file, you need to handle text files and binary files differently. If the input file format is text-base (.txt, .htm, etc.) you can mostly treat it as a string, although you still need to know what encoding to use.

If, however, the input file format is binary (like .doc, .docx, etc.), you cannot just convert your byte array directly to a string because the file contents do not represent only text - the bytes describe layout, formatting, and other information about the file. In that case you need to use Word or some other 3rd-part library to handle the file data for you.

To get the content of a Word document using automation, just create an instance of `Word.Application`, open a document, select all text in its active window and use the `Selection.Text` property to get the text into a string. Something like:

```
oDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory()
sText = oDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Text
```

The `Selection` object is an instance of [`Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195101%28v=office.14%29.aspx) in Word. This gives you the plain, unformatted content of the document. You can either convert it to a byte array or use it as a string. To convert it to a byte array, you need to use an encoding because in-memory characters must be translated to bytes.

If you want to convert your content to RTF format, you need 3rd-part tools (or implement the RTF format yourself) - RTF is not a plain text format, it has  fairly complex structure.

You can also use Word to save a document in RTF format - look up the [`Document.SaveAs2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method to do this. This saves the document to disk in RTF format. If you need this data in a database, just read the .rtf file (`File.ReadAllBytes()`) and then save the bytes to the database.

Comment: sorry for delay in response, please read my edited qus and please help me

Comment: @vikas What is your `ClsDocumentManager` class?

Comment: added ClsDocumentManager class method please review

Comment: @vikas I think you need to clean up your question. I'm losing track of what you're trying to do. You need to clearly state what it is that you're trying to achieve. With the code you added it's even more confusing.

Comment: @vikas Updated my answer about converting a Word document to RTF.

Comment: the code I have written is working in some condition when I am passing values in method its working, but when I am passing value throw property its not working